# Convert datetimeoffset to varchar

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I've searched everywhere but can't seem to find this info and it's not listed (as far as I can tell) in the MS documentation for [CONVERT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#date-and-time-styles).

Given the Date/Time/Offset: `1997-12-31 14:53:00.123 +04:30`

It's easy to cast it to `datetimeoffset(3)` as `CONVERT( datetimeoffset(3), '1997-12-31 14:53:00.123 +04:30' )`

But converting it from a `datetimeoffset(3)` back to text isn't as simple.

```
DECLARE @DateTimeOffset datetimeoffset(3) = '1997-12-31 14:53:00.123 +04:30';
DECLARE @StringDTO varchar(255) = CONVERT( nvarchar, @DateTimeOffset, 121 );
SELECT @StringDTO;
```

The two closest styles I could find were `121` and `127`:

- `121` returns `1997-12-31 14:53:00.1230000 +0` which is missing the actual TimeZone value
- `127` returns `1997-12-31T10:23:00.1230000Z` which is converting everything to Zulu time.

Does anyone know the conversion style for `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss.fff +zz:zz` / `1997-12-31 14:53:00.123 +04:30` please?

I can easily roll my own function but wanted to confirm there wasn't an existing function already in SQL Server before I did that.

Much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thats weird because style 121 [works for me](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=74bef632e36e70f173970d6143c94e33). However you can always try [`format`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) e.g.

```
DECLARE @DateTimeOffset datetimeoffset(3) = '1997-12-31 14:53:00.123 +04:30';

SELECT
    CONVERT(NVARCHAR, @DateTimeOffset, 121)
    , FORMAT(@DateTimeOffset, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff zzz');
```

Convert performs better though, so use it if you can.

However looking further at your data the issue lies in the fact that you must actually be using `datetimeoffset(6)` to have your fractions of a second to 6 decimal places. And at that point you overrun the default `nvarchar` length of 30.

So specifying a size resolves that.

```
DECLARE @DateTimeOffset datetimeoffset(6) = '1997-12-31 14:53:00.123 +04:30';

SELECT
    CONVERT(NVARCHAR(255), @DateTimeOffset, 121)
    , FORMAT(@DateTimeOffset, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff zzz');
```

Of course its best practice to always define the length of a string in SQL Server.

Comment: So embarressing, I wasn't thinking and didn't scope my conversion size, such a n00b mistake.  I was scripting a concept in a hurry and didn't think I was going to hit the 30 character conversion limit.
`DECLARE @StringDTO varchar(255) = CONVERT( nvarchar(35), @DateTimeOffset, 121 );`
Thanks for the sanity check Dale.

Comment: Yeah, and would you believe I changed it from 7 to 3 because knowing SO I was already expecting someone to nitpick at the fact that the built in SQL functions only did 3.  A series of unfortunate events!  Been burned horribly already because sometimes people get more hung up on the nitpicks than the issue.  Well spotted though :)